# Error en arreglo al tratar de subir múltiples documentos

Tags: php

Cordial saludo.

Gradezco inmensamente si alguien me puede orientar en la siguiente situación, debo subir multiples archivos a una base de datos desde localhost, el formulario y todo funciona bien para hacerlo subiendo de a un solo archivo, el tema es que son cientos de ellos, para esto he modificado el atributo input y le he puesto en su nombre tipo array es decir <name="archivo[]" multiple> para permitir seleccionar varios archivos al mismo tiempo, pero cuando hago click en el botón subir me salen los siguientes errores.

`Warning: copy() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\subirpdf\index.php on line 16`

**Código index.php**

````
include_once 'config.inc.php';
if (isset($_POST['subir'])) {
    $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
    $tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
    $ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $destino = "archivos/" . $nombre;
    if ($nombre != "") {
        if (copy($ruta, $destino)) {
            $titulo= $_POST['titulo'];
            $descri= $_POST['descripcion'];
            $db=new Conect_MySql();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO libro1(titulo,descripcion,tamanio,tipo,nombre_archivo) VALUES('$titulo','$descri','$tamanio','$tipo','$nombre')";
            $query = $db->execute($sql);
            if($query){
                echo "Se guardo correctamente";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 500px;margin: auto;border: 1px solid blue;padding: 30px;">
            <h4>Subir PDF</h4>
            <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Titulo</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="titulo"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Descripcion</label></td>
                        <td><textarea name="descripcion"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="file" name="archivo[]" multiple></td>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="subir" name="subir"></td>
                        <td><a href="lista.php">lista</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>            
        </div>
    </body>
</html> ```
````

Comment: Si subes un arreglo de archivos, tienes que recorre el arreglo para poder extraer sus elementos,algo asi:  `$countfiles = count($_FILES['archivo']['name']);
 // recorres los archivos
 for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
   $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'][$i];
$tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'][$i];
   ...//etc
    
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas hacer un recorrido por cada uno de los archivos que se adjunten a tu campo {*archivo[]*} y establecer variables para controlar aciertos y errores, mas un mensaje a mostrar en caso de éxito o fracaso (o ambos a la vez para simplificar como en este ejemplo):

```
    include_once 'config.inc.php';
    // Definimos una variable para mostrar mensajes 
    $f_msgs = '';

    if (isset($_POST['subir'])) {
        // Establecemos los valores de título y descripción de acuerdo a lo que el
        // usuario ingrese en los campos respectivos.
        $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
        $descri = $_POST['descripcion'];

        // Obtener la cantidad de archivos seleccionados en el input
        $num_files = count($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']);

        // Conexión a la base de datos
        $db = new Conect_MySql();

        // Definimos 2 variables de aciertos y errores para mostrar al usuario 
        // cuantos de estos archivos han sido copiados y cuantos no
        $f_success = 0;
        $f_error = 0;
 
        // Bucle para cada archivo seleccionado
        for ($i=0; $i < $num_files; $i++) {
            // Establecemos las variables para el archivo actual, dependiendo del
            // valor de $i
            $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'][$i];
            $tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'][$i];
            $tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'][$i];
            $ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $destino = "archivos/" . $nombre;

            // Comprobamos si hay un archivo para subir
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
                if (copy($ruta, $destino)) {
                    //Si la copia fue exitosa, agrega los datos a la tabla
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO libro1 (titulo, descripcion, tamanio, tipo, 
                        nombre_archivo) VALUES('$titulo', '$descri', '$tamanio', 
                        '$tipo', '$nombre')";
                    $query = $db->execute($sql);
                    if ($query) { 
                        $f_success++;
                    } else {
                        // Si se copia el archivo pero no se agrega a la tabla se debe
                        // marcar como error y borrar el archivo previamente copiado
                        unlink($destino);
                        $f_error++;
                    }
                } else {
                    //Marcado como error porque el archivo no se pudo copiar
                    $f_error++;
                }
            }
        }
        // Si alguno de los valores de $f_success o $f_error han interactuado con la 
        // subida de ficheros, se crea el mensaje personalizado a mostrarse al usuario
        if ($f_success + $f_error > 0) {
            $f_msgs = 'Total de registros nuevos: '.$f_success.' ['.
            $f_error.' error(es).]';
        } else {
           $f_msgs = 'No se ha podido realizar la operación para subir documentos.';
        }
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>    
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div style="width: 500px;margin: auto;border: 1px solid blue;padding: 30px;">
                <h4>Subir PDF</h4>

                <!-- Muestra el resultado del submit del formulario -->
                <span style="color:red;"><?= $f_msgs; ?></span>

                <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Titulo</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="titulo"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Descripcion</label></td>
                            <td><textarea name="descripcion"></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <input type="file" name="archivo[]" multiple>
                            </td>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="submit" value="subir" name="subir"></td>
                            <td><a href="lista.php">lista</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>            
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Saludos, he realizado este ejemplo que me sugieres pero me salen estos errores al hacer clic en el botón subir:Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\subirpdf\prueba.php on line 34

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\subirpdf\prueba.php on line 34

Comment: Perdón. Cometí un error. Ahí está editado.

Comment: - mcalonga, mil gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvio tu código, es posible aumentar la cantidad de archivos para subir, ya que he realizado un aprueba con bastantes archivos pero me ha generado un warning por que excede el número máximo de archivos permitidos, solo permite subir hasta 20 archivos.